# How can use lag to return the difference between the value of the current row and the value of the following row?

Tags: sql

I would like to ask you how to return the difference between the value of the current row and the value of the following row. 
I know that I could use lead, but I would like to try to use lag function to do the same.

What I thought was `lag(value) over (partition by id order by time desc)`, but I am not completely sure that this works.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should work with the `desc` on the sort.

You should understand that SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering, unless a column specifies the ordering.  For a column `lead()` and `lag()` do the same thing -- just the ordering of the sort is different.  What is the previous row for one is the next row for the other.

There are some small caveats.  `NULL` values might be treated differently.  And identical values result in an unstable ordering, so any matching value might be returned.

In general, `lag()` and `lead()` are used without `desc`, but that is just a convention to choose between the two functions.